# How to create .dat file with multiple spaces as delimiter from .xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I have an xlsx file, where each row corresponds to a sample with associated features in each column, as shown here:
[xlsx file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFuTM.png)

I am trying to convert this xlsx file into a dat file, with multiple spaces separating the columns, as displayed in the example below:

```
samples      property  feature1  feature2  feature3
sample1       3.0862    0.8626    0.7043    0.6312
sample2       2.8854    0.7260    0.7818    0.6119
sample3       0.6907    0.4943    0.0044    0.4420
sample4       0.9902    0.0106    0.0399    0.9877
sample5       0.7242    0.0970    0.3199    0.5504
```

I have tried doing this by creating a dataframe in pandas and using dataframe.to_csv to save the file as a .dat, but it only allows me to use one character as a delimiter. Does anyone know how I might go about creating a file like the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string representation [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) of the dataframe, imported by pandas from Excel:

```
df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
with open ('output.dat', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach to do so without using `DataFrame`. We will have more flexibility since we do all the structure ourselves from the ground up.

Suppose you have read the xlsx file and store it in the form of 2-d list as follows:

```py
lines = [['sample1', 3.0862, 0.8626, 0.7043, 0.6312],
        ['sample2', 2.8854, 0.7260, 0.7818, 0.6119],
        ['sample3', 0.6907, 0.4943, 0.0044, 0.4420],
        ['sample4', 0.9902, 0.0106, 0.0399, 0.9877],
        ['sample5', 0.7242, 0.0970, 0.3199, 0.5504]]
```

We can make use of string methods like `ljust`, `rjust`, or `center`. Right here, I just show you the use of `ljust` that takes the length as the first argument. The length will be the total width for left justification.

One could also use f-string to do padding in the format of `f'{var:^10.4f}'`.  The meaning of each component is:

- `^` represents centering (can be changed to `<` for left justification or `>` for right justification)
- `10` is the padding length
- `.4` is the number of decimal places
- `f` means float

So, here is the final script.

```py
padding1 = 12
padding2 = 10

print('samples'.ljust(padding1 + 1) + 'property  ' + 'feature1  ' + 'feature2  ' + 'feature3')
for line in lines:
    text = line[0].ljust(padding1)
    for i in range(1, len(line)):
        text += f'{line[i]:^{padding2}.4f}'
    print(text)
```